# How to loop data on html using mvc?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

[my user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyB83.png)

```html
<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Submenu", "Home") ">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/mytemplate/")img/pic1.jpg" alt="pic1" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Category Menu 1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Submenu", "Home")">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/mytemplate/")img/pic2.jpg" alt="pic2" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Category Menu 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Submenu", "Home")">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/mytemplate/")img/pic3.jpg" alt="pic3" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Category Menu 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="responsive">
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Submenu", "Home")">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/mytemplate/")img/pic4.jpg" alt="pic4" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">Category Menu 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to know how can i auto generate the pic 1 by 1..not add on code but by database.I mean example like admin want add some menu into his website so he use his dashboard to add the menu so how i can make when the admin add it,the user interface auto create the layout or pic list..just like loop php right?How can i do with mvc platform?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details that show where this data comes from and whether your view is strongly typed or any else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your model to the view and then you can iterate... assuming your model is called `PictureModel`, you can pass a list of `PictureModel` and iterate like below:

```
@model List<PictureModel>

@for(int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="responsive">
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Submenu", "Home") ">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/mytemplate/")img/@Model[i].PictureName.jpg" alt="@Model[i].PictureName" width="600" height="400">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">@Model[i].CategoryMenuName</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: can u more specific?on html just stay like that?

Comment: Yes, that's Razor though (not HTML)... it would be rendered to HTML. You need to pass your Model to View...

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your model or list to your razor view and then perform an action as needed

> for example

for loop

```
 @for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <p> @i </p>
    }
```

or foreach

```
@foreach (var x in model.list)
    {
       <p> @x </p>
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create model and pass.

```
@model List<WebMVC.Models.Images>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="responsive">
        <div class="gallery">
            <a href="@Url.Action("submenu","Home")">
                <img src=@item.path alt="pic" + @item.Sqno width="600" height="400" />
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Cagtegory Menu @item.Sqno</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```